# AWS: how to see the user1 created bucket by user2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, ceph, s3cmd

**Step 1:** User1 created the **test-bucket** & uploaded couple of files

**Step 2:** below policy is created and attached to the bucket

```
{
"Version":"2012-10-17",
"Id":"policy example",
"Statement":
 [
  {
"Effect":"Allow",
"Principal":"*",
"Action":["s3:List*","s3:Get*","s3:Put*"],
"Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::*"
   }
 ]
}
```

**Step 3:** User1 used the **s3cmd ls** and able to see the bucket

**Step 4:** User2 used the **s3cmd ls** and not able to see the bucket

**Step 5:** User2 used the **s3cmd ls s3://test-bucket** and able to see the bucket content

**Question:** Is there any way we can define the policy/access on the bucket such that User2 is able to see the bucket (as mentioned in Step 4) ??

Thanks a lot in Advance

Comment: What do you mean in step 4 when you say "not able to see the bucket"? Does it give an error (what error)? Or does it list all buckets but `test-bucket` is not included in the list?

Comment: **Side-note:** I would recommend that you use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`. The AWS CLI is updated more often and supports more features.

Comment: Do both IAM Users belong to the same AWS Account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If both IAM Users are in the same AWS Account**

The `s3cmd ls` command will **list all buckets in the AWS Account**. It uses the `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` permission. Permissions to run this command are *not* granted by a Bucket Policy because it lists *all* buckets.

If you want to grant permission to use `s3cmd ls`, then add this permission **to the IAM User**:

```json
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
         "Resource":"*"
      }
   ]
}
```

**If the IAM Users are in *different* AWS Accounts**

It is *not* possible for `test-bucket` to appear when a user in a different AWS Account lists buckets. This is because the `s3cmd ls` command lists all buckets in the current user's AWS Account. If the bucket was created in a different account, it will *not* be listed.

**And a warning...**

The bucket policy you have shown is **highly insecure**. It is granting permission for *anyone in the world* to:

- List the content of the bucket
- Upload files to the bucket
- Download files from the bucket

They could, for example, upload pirated movies and then invite other people to download the files. YOU would be charged for the Data Transfer costs involved.

It is rarely a good idea to grant `s3:List*` or `s3:Put*` permissions to `*` (which means anybody and everybody!).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

This is the example json, i shared here with my query and i didn't defined the policy with Wildcard in it.

can you share me the sample command (from CLI) to attach the policy to the user ?

Adding Policy to Bucket
~/s3cmd-2.1.0> s3cmd setpolicy test_policy.json s3://test-bucket/

Thanks a lot in Advance

Comment: Frankly, it's easiest to use the IAM Management Console, rather than attaching policies via the command-line. However, if you wanted to do it that way, you would use: [put-user-policy — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/put-user-policy.html)